# Why is 'NaN' numeric according to the warnings pragma?

Tags: perl, nan

I'm a little surprised (and scared) by the fact that the [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragma doesn't complain about 'NaN' and 'nan' being non-numeric.

Why does `warnings` not emit the customary `'Argument isn't numeric in addition (+)` for them?

**Test Case**

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE 'say 0+$_ for qw/string NaN nan fail/;'
Argument "string" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
0
0
0
Argument "fail" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
0
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN `NaN` is a valid value of a floating-point number, just like +/- infinity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

> Binary "<=>" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left
> argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right
> argument. If your platform supports NaNs (not-a-numbers) as numeric
> values, using them with "<=>" returns undef. NaN is not "<", "==",
> ">", "<=" or ">=" anything (even NaN), so those 5 return false. NaN !=
> NaN returns true, as does NaN != anything else.
>
> If your platform
> doesn't support NaNs then NaN is just a string with numeric value 0.

NaN behaves different on different platforms. It is in a way numerical as it can act as such in numerical operations. But it is also really not a number as it has undefined value.

Furthermore its behaviour is not portable as:

```
perl -E "say 'yes' if 0 == 'NaN'"
```

could yield different results on different platforms unless you use Perl 5.22 or newer.

Comment: So 'NaN' is not a number just in name? Behind the scenes it actually has a numeric representation?

Comment: @Zaid, NaN is not a number by any normal definition, but it is a valid IEEE float.

Answer (score 7):

"Not a number" is the long name for the value most often represented as "NaN". See also [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_Number). Computing with NaN is actually meaningful (it even has an actual bit-level representation in IEEE754).

Answer (score -4):

`NaN` is the numeric counterpart of `NiL` in strings.